# How to Disable User Interaction/Activity inside an HTML5 Object or iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm building a web app that also display a webpage content
inside an iframe, for example, I show http://w3schools.com inside an iframe.

I have options that let the admin decides whether the content of the iframe (in this case the w3schools) will allow other user to interact with the content or not,

I know a method of sandbox that will restrict cookies, javascript, or other things,
But I want a complete restrictions so that the user won't be able to do anything with the content inside of the iframe, or will the sandbox be the best solution?

I would like to know if there's a better solution for a complete user interaction prevention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sandbox` attribute is nice and all but it won't stop users from interacting with it's content.

A way to make it harder for users to interact with the contents is to create a transparent `<div>` overlay to cover the `iframe` or inject it into the `iframe`.

**Injecting does not work so well with cross domain protection**

Comment: For the average user this will be a sufficient solution. @Eldon Lesley: Have a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/hmaJg/

Comment: @bouscher thanks for the help! It worked great, I guess the absolute in the opaque div made it as a flow-ignored element so the iframe came beneath the div

Comment: @bouscher wrapping the iframe is much better then trying to inject it.  Injecting does not work so well with the cross domain protections.

Comment: an overlay doesn't cover tabbing into the iframe and pressing the ENTER key on elements within the iframe

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using a server-side component, but one way to prevent user interaction of a web page is to take a screenshot of it.

e.g. If logged in as a user, server has a page which simply outputs the screenshot displays it within the IFrame:

```
<iframe src="/DisableSite.aspx?url=XXX"></iframe>
```

If logged in as an admin, display the IFrame as normal.

Comment: I didn't use server component to construct the web-app, I use signalR, but the content of the iframe is definitely on the client side, so I need something from the javascript to disable the user interaction (not by the server side)